# How to get first two consecutive datetime points which do not reside within a time period using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of datetime values. I am trying to get the first two consecutive datetime values 
which reside outside of a time range using Linq. I am not sure how to do this.

Example data (can be copied into LinqPad:

```
List<DateTime> list = new List<DateTime>
            {
                DateTime.Parse("07/08/2014 01:00 AM"), DateTime.Parse("07/08/2014 02:00 AM"),
                DateTime.Parse("07/08/2014 03:00 AM"),DateTime.Parse("07/08/2014 04:00 AM"),DateTime.Parse("07/08/2014 05:00 AM"),
            };

            DateTime blackoutStartTime = DateTime.Parse("07/08/2014 02:00 AM");
            DateTime blackoutEndTime = DateTime.Parse("07/08/2014 03:00 AM");
```

I tried this which is wrong:

```
var twoHours = list.Where(e => e <= blackoutStartTime || e >= blackoutEndTime)
                .Take(2);
```

I am expecting the result to be the last two hours, 4AM and 5AM. The two hours in any example should be either before the blackout time range (if there are at least two hours) or after the blackout time range (like in example here).

Comment: Do you mean that to be || or &&. You want all the times that are before or after, but not in between. And you mean 4 and 5AM not PM.

Comment: You have only two values which fall in range - `07/08/2014 02:00 AM` and `07/08/2014 03:00 AM`. Why result should be 4PM and 5PM?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy per the question, he wants the opposite: dates outside the range. "I am trying to get the first two consecutive datetime values which reside outside of a time range"

Comment: @Hammerstein 4&5AM. I updated it. I meant with the || to try the hours before the blackout period, if none found then try the hours after the period.

Comment: If two consecutive values are outside the time range but enclose it entirely do you want them returned or not (e.g. 1AM to 4AM)?  I'm guessing you don't, and that what you really are asking for is the time ranges defined by consecutive values that lie entirely outside the blackout window?  Some answers return ranges that overlap the blackout times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not very efficient nor very readable, but you can do it in single query (see efficient solution at the bottom):

```
var twoHours = list.Where(d => d < blackoutStartTime || blackoutEndTime < d)
                   .OrderBy(d => d) // if sequence is not ordered
                   .GroupBy(d => blackoutEndTime < d)
                   .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
                   .Select(g => g.Take(2))
                   .Where(g => g.Count() == 2)
                   .SelectMany(g => g)
                   .Take(2);
```

Output:

```
7/8/2014 04:00:00
7/8/2014 05:00:00
```

Explanation:

1. Filter out dates which does not fall in range - we don't need them
2. Group all dates in two groups - dates less than range and dates bigger than range
3. Order two groups so that smaller dates group will be first
4. Select only first two dates from each group
5. Take those groups which have at least two dates
6. Project filtered result into flat sequence of dates
7. Select first two, if any

More efficient way (if sequence is sorted, otherwise you should sort it before querying) - a little improved suggestion by Jim Mischel (I would go two queries way for much better readability):

```
var twoHours = list.TakeWhile(d => d < blackoutStartTime).Take(2).ToList();

if (twoHours.Count < 2)
    twoHours = list.SkipWhile(d => d <= blackoutEndTime).Take(2).ToList();
```

What was improved - you don't need to save each query result into list. That will enumerate all items which match condition and create new list in memory. If you have many items before range, or if you have less than two items before range and many items after range - that is not what you want. So, take only first two items and save them to list. In ideal world you would enumerate only first two items an stop. If not, then you will enumerate all items till the range end + 2.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich just tried, works like it should. Make sure you are using exactly same query. See explanation for details

Comment: That's odd. I copied my code from here into linqpad and copied yours and ran the whole thing and got no results. I will read your explanation. Thanks.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich yep, I believe it's really required :)

Comment: Nice improvement over mine. I did the `ToList` on the first one (before the interval) because I assumed that he wanted the last two items that occurred before the interval. Yours returns the first two.

Answer (score 4):

I'll guess your problem is that your code returns erroneous results when you have, for example, something like:

```
[out,in,in,in,out,out]
```

That is, one time outside the range followed by some in the range, and then more outside the range. You want two consecutive items. You'll also have a problem with:

```
[out1,out2,out3,in,in,in,out4,out5]
```

Because if I read your question right you want `out2` and `out3`.

The simple-minded way to do this with LINQ is multiple queries. I assume that your list is in order:

```
var before = list.TakeWhile(d => d <= BlackoutStart).ToList();
if (before.Count >= 2)
{
    return before.Skip(before.Count-2);
}
var after = list.SkipWhile(d => d <= BlackoutEnd).ToList();
if (after.Count >= 2)
{
    return after.Take(2);
}
// Error here because you didn't have two consecutive items.
```

Offhand, I can't see a way to do it with a single LINQ query, although it might be possible to optimize what I have above.

You *could* do it with a single pass over the list with a loop, but the logic is kind of messy.

Answer (score 3):

To get *consecutive* values, use `Zip` like this:-

```
        // Assume an ordered pair of date times
        // if the later is before the start or the earlier is after the end, 
        // then there is no overlap
        Func<DateTime, DateTime, bool> outOfRange = (DateTime a, DateTime b) => 
                  b < blackoutStartTime || a > blackoutEndTime;

        var result = list.Zip(list.Skip(1), (a, b) => new { a, b })
            .Where(x => outOfRange(x.a, x.b))
            .First();
```

Doing it this way also lets you simplify the test for having an overlap with the blackout range.

This does assume that he initial list is in order, if it isn't, sort it first.

**This answer also excludes a range like 1AM to 4AM which totally encloses the blackout window whereas most other answers do not.**

Comment: Interesting approach. I went for the easier to read answer. Thanks.

Comment: Provided you can *guarantee* you'll never have a time range that encloses the blackout window it's a fine alternative, but for most people looking for time range intersection/overlap calculations this is the more useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
list.Where(d => d >= blackoutStartTime && d <= blackoutEndTime)
    .Sort((a, b) => b.CompareTo(a))
    .Take(2);
```

You might want to also sort to make sure you're indeed getting the last 2.